# Change the user role on purchase for specific products when order status is completed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, hook-woocommerce

So I helped someone launch a site and they wanted a discounted product when someone purchased a specific product. I found a solution and implemented it and it worked at launch of the site and is no longer changing the role of customers when they purchase the products. I tried to get support from Woothemes and they don't support customization and want them to purchase a $129 extension to handle this.

Does anyone out there have a solution for this that still works?

Here is my code:

```
// Update User on purchase https://gist.github.com/troydean/9322593 
function lgbk_add_member( $order_id ) {

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();

    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $product_name = $item['name'];
        $product_id = $item['product_id'];
        $product_variation_id = $item['variation_id'];
    }

    if ( $order->user_id > 0 && $product_id == '247' || $order->user_id > 0 && $product_id == '255') {
        update_user_meta( $order->user_id, 'paying_customer', 1 );
        $user = new WP_User( $order->user_id );

        // Remove role
        $user->remove_role( 'customer' ); 

        // Add role
        $user->add_role( 'author' );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'lgbk_add_member' );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Normally this updated code version should work with **`woocommerce_order_status_completed`** and then you should try this code **before**. 
*(This code is also compatible with next upcoming major WooCommerce update 2.7).*

Here is the code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'custom_action_on_completed_customer_email_notification' );
function custom_action_on_completed_customer_email_notification( $order_id ) {

    // Set HERE your targetted products IDs:
    $targetted_products = array( 247, 255 );

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    if ( $order->get_user_id() > 0 ) {
        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $order_item ) {
            // Here we detect if the a target product is part of this order items
            if ( in_array( $order_item['product_id'], $targetted_products ) ){

                // I think tha this is not really needed as it's set when an order has been paid…
                update_user_meta( $order->get_user_id(), 'paying_customer', 1 ); // 1 => true

                // Remove all roles and set 'editor' as user role (for current user)
                $user = new WP_User( $order->get_user_id() );
                $user->set_role( 'author' );

                // Product is found, we break the loop…
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But as I don't know how your order is changed to **`'completed'`** status, if you want to be sure (in all possible cases) that the customer that will buy one of your 2 specific products, will have his role changed from **`'customer`**' to **`'author'`** when order status is set to **`'completed'`**, I will recommend you trying to use this an email notification hook (if the first code snippet doesn't work).

For example here I use **`woocommerce_email_before_order_table`** hook, that will be executed and fired on "Completed order customer email notification" with the help of some conditions. 
*(This code is also compatible with next upcoming major WooCommerce update 2.7).*

Here is your revisited and tested code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'custom_action_on_completed_customer_email_notification', 10, 4 );
function custom_action_on_completed_customer_email_notification( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {

    if( 'customer_completed_order' == $email->id ){

        // Set HERE your targetted products IDs:
        $targetted_products = array( 247, 255 );

        if ( $order->get_user_id() > 0 ) {
            foreach ( $order->get_items() as $order_item ) {
                // Here we detect if the a target product is part of this order items
                if ( in_array( $order_item['product_id'], $targetted_products ) ){

                    // I think tha this is not really needed as it's set when an order has been paid…
                    update_user_meta( $order->get_user_id(), 'paying_customer', 1 ); // 1 => true

                    // Remove all roles and set 'editor' as user role (for current user)
                    $user = new WP_User( $order->get_user_id() );
                    $user->set_role( 'author' );

                    // Product is found, we break the loop…
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.